# how to disable calling ad service Api in chromium?

Tags: android, build, chromium

I'm trying to build version 116 of chromium for android according to [this page](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/refs/heads/main/docs/android_build_instructions.md). it compiles and makes `aab` file and I convert `aab` file to universal `apk` using `bundletool`. by openning chromium on device it crashes in a few seconds.

I used following args to build chromium.

```
target_os = "android"
target_cpu = "arm"
is_debug = false
is_official_build = true
symbol_level = 1
ffmpeg_branding = "Chrome"
proprietary_codecs = true
enable_nacl = false
android_channel = "stable"
disable_fieldtrial_testing_config = true
treat_warnings_as_errors = false
```

By looking log cat of chromium there is an error line in it that I guess is related to the problem. error line:

[image: error line in chromium log cat]

How can I fix this error?